# Using generic function to load from UserDefaults

Tags: swift, generics

I want to load from `UserDefaults` with a generic function:

```swift
func loadFromUserDefaults<T: Decodable>(type: T.Type, forKey key: String) -> T? {
        let decoder = JSONDecoder()
        if let data = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: key) as? Data,
           let object = try? decoder.decode(T.self, from: data) {
            return object
        }
        
        return nil
    }
```

While the above function compiles, I cannot call the function:

```swift
if let object = loadFromUserDefaults(type: MyClass.Type, forKey: "key") {
    self.myProperty = object
} else {
    MyClass()
}
```

gives me the error `Type 'MyClass.Type' cannot conform to 'Decodable'; only struct/enum/class types can conform to protocols`.

`MyClass` conforms to `Codable`, so that's not the issue.

While I think I understand the underlying error, I am failing to come up with a solutions to solve this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inherit `Decodable` protocol in your class model and call like this.

```
class MyClass: Decodable {
    
}
```

```
if let object = loadFromUserDefaults(type: MyClass.self, forKey: "key") {
    self.myProperty = object
} else {
    MyClass()
}
```

Comment: You're right, that's certainly required – as `MyClass` conformed to `Codable` before though I was not sure what the error message meant... I currently have the func in the same ViewModel – after having made that static an calling it with `Self.loadFromUserDefaults(type:forKey:) from within the initialiser, it works...

Comment: Obviously, I will want to refactor and move the function to another helper class or similar, that will be my next step.